# retrieving first rehire and terminated dates and second rehire and termination of employee

Tags: mysql

I want to write a SQL Query to fetch 1st rehire, termination date and 2nd rehire, termination dates of employee if employee doesn't having those dates then **it will display blank(null) in result.** Having table name as per_periods and date start column is contains hire/rehire date and actual termination date contains terminations dates.In image 1st&2nd re means rehire dates and 1st&2nd term means termination dates

having table data In picture follows:
[enter image description here][1]

**the query must work for all records.** can anyone guide me

if you need more info please comment in commentbox.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSqKL.png

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS; which are you using? Also, please do not post data as images; post it as text we can copy/paste (and preferably as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements we can execute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, from version 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY person_id
  ORDER     BY date_start
  MEASURES
    first_rehire.date_start               AS rehire1_start,
    first_rehire.actual_termination_date  AS rehire1_end,
    second_rehire.date_start              AS rehire2_start,
    second_rehire.actual_termination_date AS rehire2_end

  PATTERN (^ first_hire first_rehire? second_rehire?)
  DEFINE first_hire AS 1 = 1
)
```

Or, in both Oracle and MySQL, you can use:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       rehire1_start,
       rehire1_end,
       rehire2_start,
       rehire2_end
FROM   (
  SELECT person_id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start) AS rn,
         LEAD(date_start, 1)
           OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start) AS rehire1_start,
         LEAD(actual_termination_date, 1)
           OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start) AS rehire1_end,
         LEAD(date_start, 2)
           OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start) AS rehire2_start,
         LEAD(actual_termination_date, 2)
           OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY date_start) AS rehire2_end
  FROM   table_name
) t
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (person_id, date_start, actual_termination_date) AS
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1971-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '1972-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1973-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '1974-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1975-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '1976-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1977-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1971-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '1972-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1973-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '1974-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1975-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1971-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TIMESTAMP '1972-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1973-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC', TIMESTAMP '1971-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | PERSON_ID | REHIRE1_START | REHIRE1_END | REHIRE2_START | REHIRE2_END |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 01-JAN-72 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-73 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-74 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-75 00.00.00.000000000 UTC |
> | 2 | 01-JAN-72 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-73 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-74 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-75 00.00.00.000000000 UTC |
> | 3 | 01-JAN-72 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | 01-JAN-73 00.00.00.000000000 UTC | *null* | *null* |
> | 4 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bc29bda4f0fa5e527fa30542f44dcd78)*